# Problema com CKEditor no Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

Estou com problema para visualizar a janelas que são abertas pelo CKEditor, chamado a partir de um modal do Bootstrap. Elas, as janelas, abrem. Mas, apenas, por trás do modal. Alguém pode ajudar??

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução nos fórum do jQuery. Segue a solução e o link fonte:

Abra o arquivo 'config.js' do CKEditor ele vai esta mais ou menos assim:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
}
```

Então, cole a linha a baixo, entre as chaves **`{}`**:

```
config.baseFloatZIndex = 90000;
```

Resolvido! Pelo menos comigo funcionou certinho.